# Python confluent_kafka - List All Consumer currently Listening to a Topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

How to get of consumer.id which are listening to a topic using Confluent_Kafka?

I am able to get the consumer-groups and topic. But not the consumer name/id.

Comment: Basically I am looking for whether a consumer is running or not. If not running then I need to start it. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your consumers are using group functionality, you can get a list of the consumer groups using the `AdminClient` and then find each consumer that is a member of the group. it has been added in this [commit](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/commit/77681916850ec5902dd0b9f270f8274d73d81b25).

**Example snippet**

```py
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient
broker = '1.1.1.1:9092' # replace appropriately
a = AdminClient({'bootstrap.servers': broker})
groups = a.list_groups(timeout=10)
print(" {} consumer groups".format(len(groups)))
for g in groups:
    print(" \"{}\" with {} member(s), protocol: {}, protocol_type: {}".format(
        g, len(g.members), g.protocol, g.protocol_type))

    for m in g.members:
        print("id {} client_id: {} client_host: {}".format(m.id, m.client_id, m.client_host))
```

You may be interested in the `client_id` field that would differentiate the consumers in a group.

Reference: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/adminapi.py

Comment: Two Words. Awesome and Thank You

Comment: Some times even though my consumer is running it is returning zero members from group. why that behavior ? Some time there will be no message to consumer for a long time, is that causing it ?

Comment: @Marshall The consumer would likely have been kicked-out of the group, perhaps because it has failed to send heartbeats to Kafka. Enable DEBUG logs for kafka and check the issue. Also, double-check if the group you are looking is same as that of the consumer.

Comment: Additionally, you might also want to increase your `session.timeout.ms` to higher as applicable.